# Как обновить JavaFX API?

Tags: java, api, intellij-idea, javafx

Привет всем! Только начинаю знакомиться с JavaFX и обнаружил множество проблем связанных с ним. Во время сборки приложения в среде IDEA, в консоли выводится следующее предупреждение:

> WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.111 by
>   JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.66

Потому что в самом коде я указал:

```
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111"
```

И если я поменяю его на:

```
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.66"
```

то все работает, без всяких предупреждении.

Мой вопрос: "Правильно ли, то как я исправил этот Warning?" =)

И как я понял, JavaFX теперь находится в статусе Open Source и все его последующие обновления можно найти в http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/

Comment: Это всеголишь предупреждение, на работе приложения ни как не сказывается

Comment: @GenCloud да, я понимаю. Но все равно какой-то дискомфорт от этого все же есть)

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что Scene Builder сам генерирует этот параметр. Потому что, мой Scene Builder является приложением от стороннего разработчика [Gluon](http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/)

Версия Java в этом приложении 1.8.0.111, поэтому и собственно исправить его не получилось, так как на текущий момент у меня последняя версия приложения 8.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Если вы введете `xmlns = "http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111` или `xmlns =" http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.66` вместо `xmlns = "http://javafx.com/javafx` WARNING не завершится